# Mule Enterprise Security Example application won't run

Tags: maven, security, mule, enterprise

I have installed the enterprise security module into Anypoint Studio 5.4.  The Enterprise Security Example application is configured to run on Mule 3.7.3 and is mavenized, yet has all of the jars in the lib folder, including the ones following (it seems that version 1.5.1 of these jars is available, but not in the download, nor can I find maven settings for them):

```
mule-module-security-encryption-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
mule-module-security-property-placeholder-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
mule-module-security-signature-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I try and run the application I get the following error (I attached my maven settings.xml and pom.xml files):

```
ERROR 2016-01-11 17:58:30,971 [main]      
org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact                                +
+ 'anypoint-enterprise-security-example', see below        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact   
[anypoint-enterprise-security-example]
at     
org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:38) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.
3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launche
r-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at       org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDepl   oyer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launch
er-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at         org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArc    hiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-modul
e-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArc    hiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-modul
e-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at       org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArc    hiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module
-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDi    rectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-mod
ule-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatc    her.java:150) ~[mule-module-launche
r-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:1    04) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.ja
r:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~    
[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at     org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.    java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.ja
r:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
org/mule/security/signature/xml/algorithms/DigestMethodAlgorithm
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
at     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:    571) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.ja
r:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488)     
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501) 
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501) 
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501)     
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501) 
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501)   
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
at         org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:501) 
  ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
 .6.RELEASE]
 at         org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474) 
~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.6.RELEASE]
...more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>com.mulesoft.security.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>encrypted-message-producer</artifactId>
<name>Encrypted Message Producer examples</name>
<version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-security-signature</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-security-encryption</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>false</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <excludeMuleDependencies>true</excludeMuleDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Comment: If you post your POM file we will be able to help you

Comment: @MauroRocco. added pom.xml to above post.  Thanks.  FYI...the pom.xml is unmodified straight from the download from MuleSoft.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom for the dependency in the version tag you have ${project.version}, this means he will try to download the version 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT of this artifacts.
After trying on my pc I saw that he couldn't fetch it. I tried with version 1.5.1 and everything worked smoothly.

Try just to set version 1.5.1 for all your security modules in your pom.
Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: I changed the pom by replacing "1.2.1-SNAPSHOT" with "1.5.1" and it produced errors stating that the 1.5.1 jars could not be found in my local maven repo; therefore, they didn't download.  This suggestions that I don't have the correct repos setup in either settings.xml or in the pom.  Correct?  Can you share the correct repo that I should be getting 1.5.1 from?  Thx

Comment: You are aware that mule security is an enterprise product and therefore you should have an account to access mule enterprise repository ? If you don't have this than the only way to test it I think is doing it not as maven project.

Comment: I do have an account through my company.  I assumed they were correct.  I will recheck the values.  Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you have the repository defined in your pom and settings. ttps://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee. And in your settings.xml of maven the credential to access it. If you don't have a maven account just create a ticket on mule support portal.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.  In the settings.xml in the Maven installation, the Server ID for the enterprise credentials did not match the ID for the Repository.  It now deploys with version 1.5.1.

Comment: Was a pleasure helping you.